# ACL Implementation of Hyperledger fabric 1.2

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

As documented in the hyperledger document 1.2 am trying to implement Basic default ACL but no luck till now. Please find my configtx.yaml [here](https://hastebin.com/pakabakuvo.coffeescript) .There are just 2 organization Org1 and Org2. Policies are configured accordingly (But Maybe am doing wrong somewhere in configuration) with this configuration everything goes fine but at the time of channel creation `peer channel create` in CLI peer am getting the error:

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Attempted to include a member which is not in the consortium

As I know a consortium is a group of non-orderer organizations and I have added both Org1 and Org2.

Please help me if anyone has gone through this.! am using fabric 1.2 binaries.

Thanks in advance